# Is there an automatic batch job triggering facility in Linux like the JES queue for IBM mainframes?

Tags: jobs, mainframe

Is there a way to automatically trigger a job (program) on Linux by placing a file or script in a certain place like the JES queue for IBM mainframes?

I've seen daemon systems that poll or setting up cron jobs but I have never seen a system that will run scripts if you place them in a certain place on the file system.

I'm looking for something that would act like this:

```
>cat script.ksh;
!#/bin/ksh
echo 'hello'

>cp cript.ksh /job;
hello
```

Comment: The tag [tag:batch-file] is used for windows batch files, the [tag:linux] tag: `LINUX QUESTIONS MUST BE PROGRAMMING RELATED. Use this tag only if your question relates to programming using Linux APIs ...`

Comment: Maybe `fswatch` can help you detect the file system changes and then you can use that to trigger an action of some sort?